# How to read input from stdio as the whole string in Java

Tags: java, input, stdio

I did the following:

1) Created `BufferedReader`;

2) Read line by line from `stdio` and appended it to `StringBuilder`

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

StringBuilder everything = new StringBuilder();
String line;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    everything.append(line);
}
System.out.println(everything.toString());
```

But I can't exit the loop. 
When I pass, for example, such input and press `ENTER` I am still in the loop.

```
aut Caesar aut nihil
aut aut
de mortuis aut bene aut nihil
```

How can I overcome this problem? Or maybe I should use another method reading from `stdio`?

Comment: `stdin` is opened stream so there is possibility that on the other end some content is being produced and will be send, so application needs to wait for it each time you are calling `readLine()`. To solve it you can use some stop sequence to decide if you should exit the loop. Such sequence can be word like `end`, `stop`, or maybe no word at all, just empty line. So your solution could look like `while((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("stop")) {...}`

Comment: You might be able to generate an `EOF` by pressing `<Ctrl-D>`.  Depends entirely on the console you are using to run the program.

Comment: Why aren't you using the Scanner class for reading user input it is much easier than this approach.

Comment: @Manishsakpal, Could you show an example?

Answer (score -1):

This code is just a sample example for Scanner class it will just read a String input from user and store it in a String.

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter data");

    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        String str=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Comment: If I pass the strings I mentioned in question it will only print the first string. =( But I want all strings are printed.

Comment: It prints the text, sure. But then your code waits for next input. How to avoid this waiting?

Comment: what do you mean by it waits for next input?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130734/discussion-between-manish-sakpal-and-roma-karageorgievich).